# TensorFlow Sparsity Zero_Fraction Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, tensorboard

Recent `TF 1.3` has a method to report the sparsity, called [zero_fraction](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/zero_fraction), it should count the number of zero in an array and report a number [0,1].

When I train a sample MobileNet_v1 network with flowers dataset, the average sparsity reported in Tensorboard is around `0.5` for a given endpoint convolution layer (`sparsity/Conv2d_13_pointwise`), that means I should expect half of my weights in my array `arr` to be zero. However, inspecting the frozen model (`.pb`) of that does not return even single zero.

```
>>> numpy.histogram(arr)
(array([     2,      3,     23,    252,  11480, 197616,  52402,    339,
           21,      6]), array([-0.80976278, -0.66797061, -0.52617844, -0.38438628, -0.24259411,
       -0.10080194,  0.04099022,  0.18278239,  0.32457455,  0.46636672,
        0.60815889]))
>>> numpy.count_nonzero(arr==0)
0
```

Many points are actually close to zero. Does anyone know if they do any approximations in there? This is confusing and I would like to know why.

Comment: Are you measuring the sparsity of the activations (ie, the output of the layer) or the weights during training? Having zeros in the activations does not mean that your weights are zero! The [implementation of tf.zero_fraction](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b46340f40fe5e2ec9bfcd385b07cfb914055fb51/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L300)  seems to be straightforward.

Comment: @chrert, I am measuring the layer's weight. Is something wrong with that? Also, I have looked at the `test=sess.run('MobilenetV1/Conv2d_13_pointwise/weights:0')` and this also return no zero (this is the output of the activation right?)

Comment: Can you show the training code? I'm quite sure, that the tensorboard summary during training measures the zero fraction of the activations and not the weights. In contrast to relu activations, weights are usually not exactly zero. @Amir

Comment: IIUC, for sigmoids, zero activations only happen if all weights are zero, except on those connections that happen to already have zero incoming activations. So the fraction of zero activations is usually only a little larger than the fraction of zero weights (assuming the fraction of zero incoming activations is small).

Of course, in reality almost everyone uses RELU non-linearities. And for those, this argument completely breaks down: you easily get zero activations just by having a negative sum, so you can have a lot of zero activations without any zero weights at all.